# Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console

Tags: android, android-studio

I enabled save game feature in Google Developer Console but after about 36 hours my app crash with this error in Android Studio:

"Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console"

The Leader-boards and Achievements are OK. But I have problem to use save game feature.

[the APIs are enabled in API Manager Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tEj6.png)